# podman exec --env-file seemingly not working

Tags: podman

trying to run the following command:

```
podman exec -it  --env-file=./env/local.env bbss superset fab create-admin \
    --username ${BBSS_ADMIN_USERNAME} \
    --firstname ${BBSS_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME} \
    --lastname ${BBSS_ADMIN_LASTNAME} \
    --email ${BBSS_ADMIN_EMAIL} \
    --password ${BBSS_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
```

my env file looks like this:

```
BBSS_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
BBSS_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME=Adam
BBSS_ADMIN_LASTNAME=Adams
BBSS_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@xxx.com
BBSS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxx
```

however, I'll get errors indicating that my env vars are blank:

> Error: Option '--password' requires an argument.

I have used `--env-file` with `podman run` and the same env file and it works fine

Any indication of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that your *local* shell interprets variable references before executing a command. If you run...

```
podman exec mycontainer somecomand $SOMEVARIABLE
```

Then the value of `$SOMEVARIABLE` comes from your local shell, not from the shell inside the container.  To make your command work, you would need to do something like this:

```
podman exec -it  --env-file=./env/local.env bbss sh -c '
superset fab create-admin \
    --username ${BBSS_ADMIN_USERNAME} \
    --firstname ${BBSS_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME} \
    --lastname ${BBSS_ADMIN_LASTNAME} \
    --email ${BBSS_ADMIN_EMAIL} \
    --password ${BBSS_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
'
```

Here, we're using single quotes to inhibit variable expansion by the local shell, and passing the entire command to a shell in the container.

Comment: thanks, and I am following what you're saying I believe.  why I don't think this answer works for me is because I want it interpret it from the local shell.  in my example, I'm trying to run a command in the container, but pass it env var values from my local environment.  hope that makes sense